# Why my Spring Batch app auto stop and how to write data to batch database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

My `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>scheduler</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>scheduler</name>
    <description>Scheduler</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.29</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```java
package com.example.scheduler;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@EnableBatchProcessing
public class CallMethods {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                    @Override
                    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
                        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }
}
```

File `application.properties`

```java
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/scheduler
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456a@
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
# spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
# spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
# org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect

spring.batch.job.names=com.example.scheduler.CallMethods
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=embedded
spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create=
spring.batch.jdbc.platform=mysql
spring.batch.jdbc.schema=classpath:/schema-@@mysql@@.sql
spring.batch.jdbc.table-prefix=
spring.batch.job.enabled=true
```

```java
package com.example.scheduler;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SchedulerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Log

```java
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:58832,suspend=y,server=n -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.1\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\dovy\github\scheduler\target\classes;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-actuator\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.1\spring-boot-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.7.1\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.11\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.11\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.2\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.36\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.30\snakeyaml-1.30.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure\2.7.1\spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-actuator\2.7.1\spring-boot-actuator-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.3\jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.3\jackson-annotations-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.3\jackson-core-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-core\1.9.1\micrometer-core-1.9.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\hdrhistogram\HdrHistogram\2.1.12\HdrHistogram-2.1.12.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\latencyutils\LatencyUtils\2.0.3\LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-batch\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-batch-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-core\4.3.6\spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\javax\batch\javax.batch-api\1.0\javax.batch-api-1.0.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.2\jettison-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-infrastructure\4.3.6\spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.6.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\retry\spring-retry\1.3.3\spring-retry-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.21\spring-beans-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.21\spring-context-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.21\spring-tx-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.9.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.11\byte-buddy-1.12.11.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.6\jaxb-runtime-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.6\txw2-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.7.1\spring-data-jpa-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.7.1\spring-data-commons-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.21\spring-orm-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.21\spring-aspects-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.7.1\spring-boot-starter-security-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.21\spring-aop-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.7.2\spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.7.2\spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.21\spring-expression-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.21\spring-web-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\8.0.29\mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.21\spring-core-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.21\spring-jcl-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.21\spring-jdbc-5.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.7.2\spring-security-core-5.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\5.7.2\spring-security-crypto-5.7.2.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.example.scheduler.SchedulerApplication
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58832', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.1)

2022-07-14 15:34:59.066  INFO 22340 --- [           main] c.e.scheduler.SchedulerApplication       : Starting SchedulerApplication using Java 18.0.1.1 on 21AK22-COM with PID 22340 (C:\dovy\github\scheduler\target\classes started by Administrator in C:\dovy\github\scheduler)
2022-07-14 15:34:59.070  INFO 22340 --- [           main] c.e.scheduler.SchedulerApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-07-14 15:34:59.786  INFO 22340 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-07-14 15:34:59.803  INFO 22340 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-07-14 15:35:00.188  INFO 22340 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-07-14 15:35:00.614  INFO 22340 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-07-14 15:35:00.666  INFO 22340 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-07-14 15:35:00.722  INFO 22340 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2022-07-14 15:35:00.959  INFO 22340 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-07-14 15:35:01.068  INFO 22340 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2022-07-14 15:35:01.264  INFO 22340 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-07-14 15:35:01.276  INFO 22340 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-07-14 15:35:04.389  INFO 22340 --- [           main] c.e.scheduler.SchedulerApplication       : Started SchedulerApplication in 5.891 seconds (JVM running for 7.03)
2022-07-14 15:35:04.396  INFO 22340 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-07-14 15:35:04.403  INFO 22340 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-07-14 15:35:04.429  INFO 22340 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58832', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image]

Question 1: Why my Spring Batch app auto stop and how to write data to batch database?

Question 2: How to write batch job data to this SQL schema https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql ?

Comment: Add `@Configuration` to the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotated class, else it won't be detected. Regarding 2 you don't as Spring Batch will do that for you. Finally your job is named `job` not `com.example.scheduler.CallMethods`

Comment: Follow your guide, I catch error https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/0acfdef92e5c81defd2666dbd9010c18 and https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/178941488-9ed53a3e-03dd-475b-b4e6-959f0ff79bb0.png

Comment: Well have your **read** the exception... It clearly tells you what is wrong...